# ErrorAccessDenied in Microsoft Graph API while updating IsRead property of mail item

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We are using microsoft graph api for calendar and mail item processing. we pick the items from the office 365 account,process the item then we mark it as read and after that we delete that item so that it will not be processed again.
In the mark item as read process, we have below method

```
MarkReadMail()

{

var response = graphClient.Me.Messages[itemID].Request().Select("IsRead").GetAsync();

var msg = response.Result;

msg.IsRead = true;

graphClient.Me.Messages[itemID].Request().Select("IsRead").UpdateAsync(msg);

}
```

`MarkReadMail()` is working fine with office 365 business essential account but on the client side they have used office 365 enterprise account, it gives the below error:

```
Message: Exception occured in method MarkReadMail  :Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
Inner error
 Stack Trace:   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__32`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.MessageRequest.<UpdateAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
```

Although, we have provided `Mail.ReadWrite` permission under delegated permissions on both the account.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot POST the object you received from the GET as it includes read-only properties (i.e. `id`). You need to POST a new object with just the properties you wish to update:

```
graphClient
  .Me
  .Messages["itemID"]
  .Request()
  .UpdateAsync(new Message(){ IsRead = true });
```

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for your answer. But still the item does not mark as read while using office 365 enterprise account on client side  But for office 365 business essential account it is working fine.